# Move Laravel project to another system

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I tried to move my laravel 4.1 project from my office system to my personal laptop and I have tried it using various methods:
1) git and bitbucket
2) zipped whole folder and copy
3) using composer install/update on laptop directory to update my dependencies

Neither of the above has worked for me.

I do see my landing page but on clicking any link, it shows:

**Not Found**

The requested URL was not found on this server.

Seems like some routing error but I do see my index page. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could be [url rewriting](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#pretty-urls) that doesn't work properly on the new system. Try to call `yourapp/index.php/yoursubpage` instead of `yourapp/yoursubpage` to verify that.

Comment: Thanks Marcel! I verified using your suggestion, thats exactly the problem. I do not have mod_rewrite enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be a problem with the **url rewriting** on your system . make sure you fix your htaccess/nginx directives . and also make sure configurations such as **mod_rewrite** is enabled .

In future try using [**laravel homestead**](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead) , so that you have consistent environment across various workstations. It's the recommended way of working using laravel.